# CompletableFuture across microservices(JVM)

Tags: java, redis, hazelcast, ignite, completable-future

Step 1: I would like to have one `CompletableFuture<String> asyncFuture` starts in **microservice A** running a async task via say `supplyAsync`.

Step 2: Then manually complete the same future object by calling manually calling `asyncFuture.complete(T value)` from a DIFFERENT **microservice B** which would be triggered by some async event.

Apparently **microservice A** and **microservice B** have different JVMs.
In reality microservice A and microservice B are different instance of the same microservice running on different pods in kubernetes.

Between Step 1 and Step 2 , the future object will be stored in Redis which microservice B can retrieve safely.

---

After some quick googling, I think I am gonna try a couple of solution below:

1> HazelCast's Distributed Executor Service which I can pass in as a second parameter when calling

```
static <U> CompletableFuture<U> supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier, Executor executor)
```

Ref:
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/2.3/manual/html/ch09.html

2>Use shared executorService from apache ignite

Ref: https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.2/docs/executor-service

Not sure if either would work ? Also I am wondering has anyone has dealt with something like this before ? If so I would appreciate if you could share your solution with me.

Comment: My two cents: you are asking one jvm to finish a thread started by another jvm. It does not sound sane of safe

Comment: It is strange that you would create your future via `supplyAsync()` and then manually `complete()` it. Although not strictly forbidden, the usual pattern is that your `Supplier` will provide the result, and you thus don't need to call `complete()`. Otherwise the result of the `Supplier` will be ignored/lost.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Apache Ignite, there are a lot of options how to cooperate nodes (microservices). One of them is Continuous Queries [1] which allow listening to data modifications occurring on caches.

For example, on service A you can create ContinuousQuery and wait for value is changed in the cache:

```
private String waitForValueChanged(IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache, Integer key) throws InterruptedException {
    ContinuousQuery<Integer, String> qry = new ContinuousQuery<>();

    qry.setInitialQuery(new ScanQuery<>((k, v) -> k == key));

    final CountDownLatch waitForValueChanged = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final AtomicReference<String> result = new AtomicReference<>();

    CacheEntryUpdatedListener<Integer, String> listener = new CacheEntryUpdatedListener<Integer, String>() {
        @Override public void onUpdated(Iterable<CacheEntryEvent<? extends Integer, ? extends String>> iterable) throws CacheEntryListenerException {
            for (CacheEntryEvent<? extends Integer, ? extends String> entry: iterable) {
                result.set(entry.getValue());
            }

            waitForValueChanged.countDown();
        }
    };

    qry.setLocalListener(listener);

    try (QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<Integer, String>> cur = cache.query(qry);) {
        waitForValueChanged.await(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    return result.get();
}
```

On service B you just need to put the value into the cache to "complete the future":

```
private void completeFuture(IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache, Integer key, String value) {
    cache.put(key, value);
}
```

Here is an example project which shows how Continuous Queries work [2].

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs#section-continuous-queries

[2] https://github.com/gromtech/ignite-continuous-query-example